# MySql - Multitable - AND is not the correct choice, but what is?

Tags: mysql, logic

I have two tables:

mytable1

```
UserId (int) (primary_key)
Save (blob)
```

mytable2

```
UserId (int) (primary_key)
Save (blob)
```

I make the following mysql command:

```
 UPDATE mytable1 tb1, mytable2 tb2 SET tb1.Save='', tb2 .Save='' WHERE tb1.UserId=25 AND dbSv1.UserId=25
```

When both tables have a user with UserId = 25, then this works and Save is set to ''. However, if one table does not have a user with UserId = 25, but the other one does, then Save is not set to '' in the one that does. This is not the behaviour I want.

OR is not the thing to use, as other Saves will be set to '' which do not have an UserId of 25. So what do I need?

Comment: Put 2 statements in a transaction

Comment: How do you do that with a single mysql statement? (I know how to do that with multiple call to mysql in php, but would prefer to avoid that and make a single mysql call.)

Comment: You can't do that in a single sql statement. But most mysql extensions support the exution of multiple sql statements in a single call. But if you use transactions, it does not really matter how many calls you make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is using the old-school comma syntax for a join operation. (There's some problems in the SQL... `dbSv1` is used as a qualifier, but it doesn't appear as a table name or table alias.  We're going to assume that was supposed to be `tb2`.

Your query is equivalent to:

```
  UPDATE mytable1 tb1
    JOIN mytable2 tb2
     SET tb1.save=''
       , tb2.save=''
   WHERE tb1.userid=25
     AND tb2.userid=25
```

If a matching row is not found in either `tb1` or `tb2`, the the JOIN operation will produce an empty set. This is expected behavior.

Consider the result set returned from this query:

```
  SELECT tb1.userid
       , tb2.userid
    FROM mytable1 tb1
    JOIN mytable2 tb2
   WHERE tb1.userid=25
     AND tb2.userid=25
```

when there are no rows in tb2 that satisfy the predicates, the query won't return any rows.

You could use an "outer" join to make returning rows from one of the tables optional.  For example, to update `mytable1` even when no matching rows exist in `mytable2`...

```
  UPDATE mytable1 tb1
    LEFT
    JOIN mytable2 tb2
      ON tb2.userid=25 
     SET tb1.save=''
       , tb2.save=''
   WHERE tb1.userid=25
```

If there are no rows in `mytable1` that have userid=25, then this won't update any rows.

MySQL doesn't support `FULL OUTER JOIN`. But you try something like this, using an inline view to return a row, and then performing outer joins to both mytable1 and mytable2...

```
  UPDATE ( SELECT 25 + 0 AS userid ) i
    LEFT
    JOIN mytable1 tb1
      ON tb1.userid = i.userid
    LEFT
    JOIN mytable2 tb2
      ON tb2.userid = i.userid
     SET tb1.save = ''
       , tb2.save = ''
```

SQLFiddle demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f8598/1

---

**FOLLOWUP**

A "join" is a common SQL operation. You shouldn't have any trouble finding out information about what that is what it does.

The "+ 0" isn't strictly necessary. It's a convenient shorthand in MySQL to CAST to numeric. As a test, see what MySQL returns for this:

```
SELECT '25' + 0
     , '25xyz' + 0
     , 'abc' + 0
```

The purpose of the inline view was to return a single row. We could have written the query to hardcode the user_id two times, and ignore what's returned from the line view ....

```
 SELECT t1.user_id AS t1_user_id
      , t2.user_id AS t2_user_id
   FROM ( SELECT 'foo' AS dontcare ) i 
   LEFT
   JOIN mytable1 t1
     ON t1.user_id = 25
   LEFT
   JOIN mytable t2
     ON t2.user_id = 25
```

My preference is to make it more clear that our intent is for both of the values to be the same. We could code where one of them is 23 and the other is 27. That's syntactically valid to do that. When we convert this to a prepared statement with bind placeholders...

```
 SELECT t1.user_id AS t1_user_id
      , t2.user_id AS t2_user_id
   FROM ( SELECT 'foo' AS dontcare ) i 
   LEFT
   JOIN mytable1 t1
     ON t1.user_id = ?
   LEFT
   JOIN mytable t2
     ON t2.user_id = ?
```

We kind of "lose" the idea that those two values are the same. To get that hardcoded value specified only one time, I have the inline view return the value we want to "match" in the ON clause of the outer joins.

```
 SELECT t1.user_id AS t1_user_id
      , t2.user_id AS t2_user_id
   FROM ( SELECT  ?  AS user_id ) i 
   LEFT
   JOIN mytable1 t1
     ON t1.user_id = i.user_id
   LEFT
   JOIN mytable t2
     ON t2.user_id = i.user_id
```

Now my intent is more clear... I'm looking for "one" user_id value. Adding the  "+ 0" indicates that whatever value gets passed in (e.g. '25', 'foo', or whatever), my statement is going to interpret that as a numeric value.

*inline view*

I used the term "inline view". That's just a SELECT query used in a context where we usually have a table.

e.g.  if i have a table named `mine`, i can write a query...

```
  SELECT m.id, m.name FROM mine m
```

test it and see that it returns rows, yada, yada.

I can also do this:  wrap that query in parens and reference it *in place* of a table in another statement, like this...

```
  SELECT t.*
    FROM ( SELECT m.id, m.name FROM mine m ) t
```

MySQL requires that we assign an alias to that, like we can do if it were a table. We call that an *inline view* because it's similar to the pattern we use for a *stored view*. Let's look at a demonstration of doing that.

(This is just a demonstration of the pattern; there's some reasons we wouldn't want to do this.)

```
  CREATE VIEW myview
  AS
  SELECT m.id, m.name FROM mine m
  ;
```

Then we can do this:

```
  SELECT t.* FROM myview t
```

With the *inline view* we're following the same pattern, but we're bypassing a separate `create view` statement. (That's a DDL statement that causes an implicit commit, and creating a database object.)  Bypassing that, we're effectively creating a view that exists only in the context of the statement, and doing that "inline", within the statement.

```
  SELECT t.* FROM ( SELECT m.id, m.name FROM mine m ) t
```

The MySQL documentation refers to the inline view as a "derived table". If we (accidentally) forget the alias, the error we get back says something like "every derived table must have a alias". The more general term, used for databases other than MySQL is "inline view".

Comment: Thanks @spencer7593, this is a great answer. I am not certain what JOINs are, but it is the perfect answer, as it has the fiddle to show it works, so I can go away and find out what it all means, then come back and understand. Thanks again. I am a hobby programmer and this is the perfect answer for someone who is keen to learn.

Comment: After some reading I literally understand everything. It is just the very last blue-bit of code. I do not know what an inline view is and cannot seem to find it on google. Is this what you are doing? The phrase after the UPDATE is where the database-table would be. You are selecting the number 25 and calling it userid. Then you are renaming this to i. With LEFT JOINS you will then get everything with the number 25 from the two joins, because that is what LEFT joins do - it is the thing on the left (the 25) that has to be valid. I almost understand, Can you explain the first line, eg why +0?

Comment: Added a followup to the question to address your comments. I hope that helps explain why I did it the way I did it.

Comment: Thanks, your follow-up really explains things. I understand now.